# Inlcuding animated PNG (APNG) in PowerPoint?

Tags: animation, powerpoint, apng

A simple question, with hopefully a simple answer:
I have a few animated PNGs (APNG) which I would like to include in a PowerPoint presentation (not tied to a specific version, but I currently use the 2019 one - could update if relevant).
Every attempt to add the APNG ends up in a static image.

Additional info:
I have tried converting to GIFs, but those come out horrible due to color limitations, while the other options is a conversion to a video (say mp4).
I would like to avoid either as they generate other problems, while including mp4s is my fallback plan.
I still have reasons to avoid either case.

Comment: PowerPoint doesn't support animated PNGs, it seems. That apparently being the case, there's not much you can do about it other than the workaround you've already found. However, it'd be a good idea to use File | Send Feedback to request that APNG support be added to PowerPoint.

Comment: I was afraid this is the situation... My main issue with GIF is that I have too many colors and it creates horrible bisual artifacts (and lowers the quality significantly if any compression is used)

Comment: Until PPT supports APNGs, you might want to try other software to convert them to GIFs. Some support dithering and other tricks to give you a better result visually than just converting to nearest color out of GIFs maximum palette of 255. For Windows, IrfanView (irfanview.com) is free and quite capable.

Comment: Powerpoint supports WebP as of August 2021: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-insider/add-webp-images-to-office-creations/td-p/2629808